# What does yellow triangle on the left side of code mean, in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ethereum, solidity

These two functions enable transfer of funds to a smart contract:

[image: These two functions enable transfer of funds to a smart contract]

solidity: 0.8.6

Comment: It's a warning. Something is potentially wrong with your `admin` variable. Hover your mouse over it and it will display full text

Comment: Take in consideration that each one of us has a different "build" on their vscode depending on their plugins installed and whatnot. But usually hovering your mouse over the icon will get you more info.

Answer (score 1):

Usually that is a code warning or error, maybe your admin address variable is not declared.

```
contract Example {
address admin;
...
function example(address admin) external payable {
//function body
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response djd. admin variable is declared in state, and an address is assigned inside the constructor.

I am beginning to assume this could be a compiler issue for two reasons

1] I am able to successfully deploy the contract to public testnet.
2] If i create a second address as payable eg: address payable fundsForwardAddress, & assign admin address to it, inside the constructor as

fundsForwardAddress = payable(admin); and when i use this fundsForwardAddress inside the receive() or fallback as fundsForwardAddress.transfer(msg.value), the yellow triangle disappears.